# React Native WebView file download/upload not working in Android

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, webview

I am developing a `react-native` application and in it i am using the `WebView` component to render web pages inside the app. But i cannot download the files from the website in the `android` mobile app.

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <WebView
          source={{ uri: 'https://********** }}
          ref={'WEBVIEW_REF'}
          startInLoadingState={true}
          scalesPageToFit={true}
          onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationStateChange.bind(this)}
          javaScriptEnabled={true}
     />
</View>
```

I found there are issues reported in the GitHub react-native repository and still they are open. But is there any solution for this ?

Comment: before changing to webView to android webView you can give this demo a shot 

https://github.com/loiclouvet/react-native-webview-file-upload

Answer (score 5):

> ReactNative's WebView on Android does not support file input.
>
> You can use this npm Module:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-webview-file-upload-android

- File input for any type of file Support for downloading files using
  the Android DownloadManager
- Permission requests for Android SDK
- Version >26 (required for new Play Store builds now, and for updates 
  from November 2018)

Comment: what is meant by this "Permission requests for Android SDK" ?

Comment: Android needs USER Permission https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview

Comment: i have used this but i cannot open the downloaded files since it's extension was not there.

Comment: try to add an extension to download the file and please upvote and mark the answer, It will help me Thank u.

Comment: but this doesn't work. where should i need to change the code ?